# Android Application Development - Problems with camera application

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple application designed to make use of the Camera API and take a photo and then save it. I'm receiving some strange errors at Runtime and get the text "Unfortunately, CameraDemo has stopped."

I got the code from this tutorial: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

the `mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);`is apparently now deprecated. Is there any alternative because I think this is causing the problem.

Here is my logcat error log file as well:

[image: logcat error print]

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?
Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Line 37 from the Preview code looks like it is the line after you have called camera.open()  Are you sure that has not failed and returned you a null camera object?

Comment: yeah there is something in the logcat about a NullPointerException but to me it looks like it's been created as a global variable and opened in with `camera = Camera.open();`

Comment: when you stop in the debugger is camera null?

Comment: yes just ran the debugger with a breakpoint set at `camera = Camera.open();` and the value is null. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Did you add the camera permission to the Manifest?

Comment: Also, is this a device or the emulator?  Does the device have a back facing camera?

Comment: I added the camera permission and this is in the Emulator.

Comment: Well, assuming you created the emulator with a rear facing camera then I don't know why you are getting the Camera.open to return null. That should only happen if there is no camera as far as I know.

Comment: I will check if I set up my AVD with a rear facing camera. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've set it up with a rear facing camera but camera value is still null!